# Error Provisioning Azure Resource (Ubuntu)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I keep getting this error while provisioning Ubuntu 16.04 resources on Azure

```
Cron root@ServerNamevmss [ ( ! -f /etc/opt/omi/creds/omi.keytab ) -o ( /etc/krb5.keytab -nt /etc/opt/omi/creds/omi.keytab ) ] && /opt/omi/bin/support/ktstrip /etc/krb5.keytab /etc/opt/omi/creds/omi.keytab

src kt = /etc/krb5.keytab
**File /etc/krb5.keytab does not exist**
/opt/omi/bin/support/ktstrip: 38: exit: Illegal number: -1
```

Anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: How do you reproduce this error? Please show the steps then I may validate it.

Comment: Hi @NancyXiong and thanks for the comment. The deployment script we ran was from https://github.com/microsoft/oxa-tools.  All the servers that are created using this deployment script seem to have this issue which seems to be related to the https://github.com/microsoft/omi package. We are still investigating